# How do I create a proper user with django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

- If I've an emailadress only
- If I don't care about a password atm (user will login through a "token link" later)

In pure Django I would just do it like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(username=email, email=email)
```

But django allauth comes with this `EmailAdress` stuff. Do I just have to create one of these too and then I'm fine?

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
EmailAddress.objects.create(user=user, email=email, primary=True, verified=False)
```

I don't want to break some django allauth logic and the [existing adapter methods](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances) doesn't suit my needs.

**EDIT**: replaced `setup_user_email` with `EmailAddress`

**EDIT2**: replaced `add_email` with `create`, want to set `primary=True`

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to create a user seems to be stuck in the `SignupForm.save()` method:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/6b2167ca245558317be1f8881f162f4d5312eb95/allauth/account/forms.py#L401-L408

Edit: It's actually one level higher in the `SignupView`, which first calls the `SignupForm.save()` and then calls `account.utils.complete_signup()`, which sends the `user_signed_up` signal:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/6b2167ca245558317be1f8881f162f4d5312eb95/allauth/account/views.py#L227-L237

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/6b2167ca245558317be1f8881f162f4d5312eb95/allauth/account/utils.py#L171-L183

Comment: `complete_signup` is fine, but to add `EmailAddress` to your account, but you have to call  `setup_user_email(request,user,[])`.

Answer (score 0):

It was so eerie to come across a question that so precisely described my own usecase! I couldn't find an answer anywhere, so I did a bit of digging in the django-allauth repository. Here's my solution -

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
data = {
        'email': 'john@leapoffaith.com',
        'password1': 'Password@99',
        'password2': 'Password@99',
    }

form = SignupForm(data)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(request)
```

Use this code anywhere in your views.py file and you should be good to go.